# Meteor: Update multiple entries in a database by their id's

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need help with the line for meteor that updates multiple entries in the database.  The first Entries.update below does not work I believe because meteor now requires you to update by id.

```
'click #draw': ->
      winner = _.shuffle(Entries.find(winner: {$ne: true}).fetch())[0]
      if winner
        Entries.update({recent: true}, {$set: {recent: false}}, {multi: true})
        Entries.update(winner._id, $set: {winner: true, recent: true})
  Template.entry.winner_class = ->
    if this.recent then 'highlight' else ''
```

So I tried to change to the below code.   However, it does not work properly since it appears as it only changes one id (the first one).

```
'click #draw': ->
  winner = _.shuffle(Entries.find(winner: {$ne: true}).fetch())[0]
  recent_winner = Entries.find(recent: true).fetch()
  if winner
    Entries.update(recent_winner._id, {$set: {recent: false}}, {multi: true})
    Entries.update(winner._id, $set: {winner: true, recent: true})
Template.entry.winner_class = ->
  if this.recent then 'highlight' else ''
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to modify multiple docs at once via Meteor.methods. From [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#update):

> The behavior of update differs depending on whether it is called by
>   trusted or untrusted code. Trusted code includes server code and
>   method code. Untrusted code includes client-side code such as event
>   handlers and a browser's JavaScript console.
>
> Trusted code can modify multiple documents at once by setting multi to
>   true, and can use an arbitrary Mongo selector to find the documents to
>   modify. It bypasses any access control rules set up by allow and deny.
>   The number of affected documents will be returned from the update call
>   if you don't pass a callback.
>
> Untrusted code can only modify a single document at once, specified by
>   its _id. The modification is allowed only after checking any
>   applicable allow and deny rules. The number of affected documents will
>   be returned to the callback. Untrusted code cannot perform upserts,
>   except in insecure mode.

EDIT:

By way of example, a method call might look something like this:

```
"click #draw": function(){
  var winner = _.shuffle(Entries.find({winner: {$ne: true}}).fetch())[0];
  if (!!winner){
    Meteor.call(
      "drawWinner", //an arbitrary method name of your choosing
      winner, // passing it your winner
      function(error, result){ // an optional async callback
        if (error){
          // handle error if error from method
        } else {
          // handle any return object from method
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And then in your method call, which might be placed in a shared directory such as 'lib' or in a server side-only directory (see the Meteor documentation for more on this point):

```
Meteor.methods({
  "drawWinner": function(winner){
    Entries.update({recent: true}, {$set: {recent: false}}, {multi: true});
    Entries.update(winner._id, {$set: {winner: true, recent: true}});
    return winner; //or the like
  }
});
```

Comment: would you be willing to demonstrate this through the code? I am trying to get the meteor method to work but am failing

Comment: Thank you, here is a helpful gist for any others on how to best structure the above code within an app: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2387816

Comment: Currently am not able to have this function correctly. First update() is successful, the rest are not.